# Rails Version Control

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, version-control

I have been following a guide to install an app called sharebox within rails. Currently I am using rails 3.2 but have just realised the guide uses rails 3.0.3.

My first question as a newbie to the rails world is what are the differences between the 2 versions and what would make the app not be fully functional on 3.2

Secondly is there a way to make the app compatible  on 3.2 or do i need to use 3.0.3?

Thanks as always

Comment: yes, but hoping someone could give a brief explanation. being new to programming a simplified answer would help me understand better

Comment: Thanks for your "helpful" comments Sergio. Ive looked into RVM which i use to control my Ruby versions, but dont understand how to manage rails versions at the same time.. If i dont understand the documentation how can i learn from it? Hence the reason i am asking.

Comment: You misunderstand the term "source control". That refers to a system by which you can keep track of changes to the files in a project, so you can undo changes, etc. The Rails project does of course use version control, but that doesn't have much to do with a user of Rails having the right version of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My first question as a newbie to the rails world is what are the
>   differences between the 2 versions and what would make the app not be
>   fully functional on 3.2

Release notes at your service: [Rails 3.2](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_2_release_notes.html), [Rails 3.1](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_1_release_notes.html)

> Secondly is there a way to make the app compatible on 3.2 or do i need
>   to use 3.0.3?

If `sharebox` is commercial project then vendor should have an answer for that. In either case you can test compatibility with 3.2 by yourself and report issues to project developers.

> Ive looked into RVM which i use to control my Ruby versions, but dont
>   understand how to manage rails versions at the same time..

You need to use [gemsets](https://rvm.io/gemsets/) in pair with editing Rails (and its dependencies) version in Gemfile.

P.S. `Sergio Tulentsev` is totally right. If you are to do this project, you have to catch up on Ruby and Rails ecosystems (rvm, rvm gemsets, bundler, Gemfile etc.).
Development of projects in ruby (and especially Rails) community is very intensive,  you won't survive asking everything on SO. Conclusion: Learn to read the docs, rdocs, rspecs etc. :)

I wish you best of luck in your beginning(s).

Comment: Thank you for your constructive response former, everyone starts somewhere and I am reading as much as possible, it's all new though and will take time...thans again